# ember.js include custom js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Attempting to wrap my head around Ember.js.
Seems I understand the complex things, but miss out on the little things.

How would one go about adding an example.js file?
For simplicity, let's say the example.js file only contains:

```
(function(){
  console.log("example is alive in console");
})(window);
```

This should display "example is alive in console" within the browser console.

I have tried:
adding `app.import('vendor/javascripts/example.js');` within ember-cli-build.js and adding `<script src="{{rootURL}}vendor/javascripts/example.js"></script>` to index.html

Console is showing

> ⓧ GET http://localhost:4200/vendor/javascripts/example.js
>   DEBUG: -------------------------------
>   DEBUG: Ember      : 2.11.3
>   DEBUG: Ember Data : 2.12.1
>   DEBUG: jQuery     : 3.2.1
>   DEBUG: -------------------------------
>   ⓧ GET http://localhost:4200/vendor/javascripts/example.js

All of the answers I have found stated that just adding custom.js to vendor file works.  Sadly, I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me when I *don't* nest assets in the `/vendor` directory. The ember-cli build process bundles JS files in `/vendor` into a single `vendor.js` file, which you can see linked in `app/index.html`. So place your `example.js` file at the *root* of `/vendor`, and then add the import to `ember-cli-build.js`:

`` app.import('vendor/example.js`); ``

Now when you start the server, your code from `example.js` should execute, since it will be included in `assets/vendor.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the validation.  I switched file to root, same issue.  Then put it back /javascripts/example.js and removed the '<script src="{{rootURL}}vendor/javascripts/example.js"></script>' from index.html and RESTARTED the ember server.  See, knew it was something silly.  When modifying ember-cli-build.js you MUST RESTART the ember server manually.  The livereload server will not pick up the changes.

Answer (score 2):

When modifying ember-cli-build.js you MUST RESTART the ember server manually. The livereload server will not pick up the changes.

Comment: Your answer made me realize that, my path name was wrong... *sigh* It's always something silly :P Your answer deserves to be the accepted answer, even if your'e also the person asking the question ;-) Thanks for making me realize my mistake :D

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, Ember.js has `Convention Over Configuration` approach, and your `URL` can do a lot of things than a normal HTML website.

Whatever you may want to do with your custom.js file it is not ember way of having it as a path. You need [routes](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/defining-your-routes/) for navigation across the app. Although routes do much more than navigation. You specify the structure of your app that a user can browse through using `Router's` `map` function in `app/router.js` file.

However if you want to include custome.js file in your app, and have custom.js do some set of tasks for your app. You can simply go ahead and create a directory with any name, `javascript` for instance inside `app` directory. Have your javascript files placed inside it. Then you can import these files as simply as referencing any other files in ember:

```
import customObject from 'yourApp/javascript/custom.js';
```

Here, your `custom.js` should be exporting `customObject`.

Do read the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/) if you want to learn more. And the [API docs](https://emberjs.com/api/) if you actually want to learn more.

Note: At the time of writing this answer current ember-cli version is @2.12.0

Comment: "Read guides and API docs" is vague and unhelpful for me and all future viewers.  I have read them through several times and still could not find a specific mention of custom js inclusion that does a simple task, like start a timer or display a console message.  Where would your recommendation be based from within the guides/API?  I seem to have skipped an important chapter!